# Can any of these files execute virus on a server?

Tags: php, upload, document, virus

Can any of the below file types execute a virus or harm the server in any way?

pdf, .png, .jpg, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .pptx, .gif.

Comment: Any file can contain a virus. The extension can easily be modified regardless of the actuall contents.

Comment: Only if you have weird server settings that would parse those files as other filetypes, such as `.php|.asp|.jsp` etc.

Comment: The best way to assure none of files can be executed in your server is remove extensions when users upload files to your server, ofcourse you are going to store each extension for each file had been uploaded, and when user request a file, then you restore extension to file in fly.

Comment: @SIFE, so then you just put it together and let them download it? Great.   Post this in the answers so i can choose your solution as the answer.

Comment: @SIFE but when you allow doc uploading an extension is required for storage no?

Comment: @AAA: no, no and no. You're on the wrong path. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The question itself has no reason to be*, as the answers given so far (I'm sorry to tell this). Don't take all of this as a criticism: I explain myself.

You can even upload **TheWorstVirusInTheWorld.exe** on your server, but it won't be harmful until it's actually executed. Unless the operating system and/or its shell or other programs (or scripts) have severe bugs, no code is executed *automagically*, in the sense of 'without the sysadmin knowing'.

See virustotal.com. They are requesting you to upload suspicious executables in order to tell whether they're viruses or not. Do they fear this? Hell no. That's because the file is uploaded on the server, and then *read* by a tool you can call 'antivirus' that doesn't execute them.

So the question can be this one: "which kind of files can be safely *executed* on my server?" The answer is: no files coming from unknown sources. The extension of the files is totally irrelevant: on UNIX systems you can execute **any** file (even .doc) that has the 'execute' bit (=attribute) set.

Hackers and lamers won't act as you expect. They're not uploading common viruses on your server, and if they do, they have to execute them, and if they can execute **something** on your server, *well your server is already gone*, and all your efforts to sanitize file extensions are rubbish.

Comment: I am confused here.  Execute means that they are able to let the file open.  If i am allowing folks to store and download isn't that the same?  And yes we do have anti-virus on our servers.

Comment: I believe he's asking more along the lines of remote exeuction via HTTP, his question is posted under "PHP" and "Upload"

Comment: @donatJ: indeed, so I explain why it's irrelevant to care about file extensions. Some hacker finding a flaw in the system may execute a '.doc' and if he/she can, if he/she can execute anything, then you're gone. So the question is not well formed. '.doc' files can harm the server? Yeah, like .exe or .bat or .nothing

Comment: @Giacomo but presuming he's running apache, apache cares about file extensions in when it actually goes about executing something via HTTP

Comment: @AAA: let them store and download viruses, if they want to. Your only concern is that nobody will actually **run** something, in the sense of making them *start* just like when you double click SomeExecutable.exe on your Windows box.

And, just for you to know, a .doc can be executed, if it contains valid executable data in a proper format for the OS.

And just to clarify, there's NO need of an antivirus on a server. If a  hacker can run anything, then he/she has your server in his pocket. Your AV software will be soon rubbish.

Comment: @Giacomo:  Thanks.  Just to confirm i am not letting any file run on the server, we were planning to let the documents show as in using flex viewer but we are not doing that now. so the only thing they can do is download.  so i am ok as long as i am only allowing them to download, correct?

Comment: Sure, but if you have some back-office, like administrative, legal staff etc... that can *grab* those files uploaded by the users and open/edit/*run* them on their Windows boxes, **THEN** you have to sanitize file extensions. But that has nothing to do with server security.

Comment: yeah like you said all i am concerned with is my server security, if they uploaded a virus infused file then they will download it but nothign wont happen to the server.

Comment: btw, doesn't executable mean to open a file too? sorry i am a bit nervous now that i have seen the difficulties with this.

Comment: Unless your server has severe flaws that would be very dangerous whether they upload a virus, or not. :)

Comment: @AAA: no need to be nervous. Well when you double-click a file on your Windows home box, then an executable is run, but not the file itself, it's a program which is supposed to open that kind of file. WINWORD.EXE opens .DOC files.
The .DOC file may turn into 'executable' if you rename the file changing its extension from .DOC to .EXE, but it has to contain proper executable stuff, so that it will result as an invalid DOC file, but a valid executable.
The file extension is a poor way to identify the file type.

Comment: @donatJ: (replying to your comment, didn't see it). If he's running Apache and someone uploads a .php and runs it with `http://someserver/uploadedfiles/myuploadedfile.php`, then the problem is not that he made someone upload it, the problem is that he made someone launch it. The /uploadedfiles/ directory should be not externally accessible and the access to those files should be mediated by some proper tool. Upload/download tools are sophisticated stuff. If the whole security on the server is left to randomness, then I correct myself: please sanitize file extensions, at least.

Comment: @giacomo how can someone change the extension if i am only allowing pdf, and .doc etc..

Answer (score 3):

@AAA: The process will be like so:

1) The user upload a file, say test.exe.

2) When it received by server, you extract the extension and store it in database with the name of file, so you can know witch file have type extension.

3) When a user request a file , you query both file extension and its name, assemble them and finally send it to user.

**Note:**
You may have duplicate name problem, it will be better if you generate a fixed length of random string and past it with file name in begging of file name as example.

Comment: +1 for the encapsulation hint and integration with database. This is what I call a proper upload/download solution.

Answer (score -2):

Noting that this is listed under 'PHP Upload", I believe he's talking about remote exeuction.  If that is the case they should all be safe.  The usual list of things I block is in this htaccess list here

```
<Files ~ "\.(php|php3|php4|php5|phtml|pl|py|psp|js|jsp|cgi|util)$">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny From All
</Files>
```